# UITextView returnKeyType

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I'm trying to change the "Return" key on a UITextView (not UITextField) to a "Done" key. I have the following code that doesn't update the button and leaves the button unchanged. The button starts as a "return" key and if they hit "return" once I want it to change to a "done" key.

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    // this is only run when they hit return once
    textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [textView reloadInputViews];
}
```

Comment: So you have an on page button with a value of RETURN and you want it to change to DONE when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes it's the pop-up keyboard on an iphone. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Oh okay I get it now.... Maybe some JavaScript or Jquery would do the trick

Comment: Could i not just do it in objective C? I've seen many posts of people getting it to work on UITextFields and they're almost the same thing.

Comment: I am not sure as I have never done anything with iOS keyboard software, but let me know what you find out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than a clean solution, this is a bit of a hack. You could try to hide and show the keyboard (i.e. `resignFirstResponder`, change the return key style and `becomeFirstResponder`).

But it will produce a weird animation. To avoid this glitch, you should be able to prevent the screen from being refreshed.

BTW, at the end of this method, do you return `YES` or `NO`?

Comment: I added the resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder and the button changes correctly, however I can't avoid the weird animation. How do I prevent the screen from being refreshed? At the end of the method I have a return YES. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to retrieve the code somewhere but failed… Maybe you should create an other question dedicated to that.

Comment: I'm not seeing the keyboard animation in iOS6.1 or in iOS7.